# Store XML fragment in Project Resources

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, resources

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on openXML [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/09/02/openxml-format-insert-an-image-into-a-document/).

I don't follow the bit where he talks about *storing an XML fragment in project resources*.

He can then obtain a copy of the XML fragment easily with

`String content = Properties.Resources.XmlContentForEmbedImage;`

I don't know how to do this, and I've googled without finding anything? What does *store the XML fragment in project resources* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by performing the following steps:

- Add a new item to your project;
- Select "Resource File" as its type;
- Double click (open) the newly created item;
- Change the current type (begins with "String") to "Files" by clicking the drop down box;
- Click "Add resource";
- Change the file type to "*.*";
- Choose the XML file you want to add.

The file is now added as a resource. You can use this in the manner described in your web page. The name of the resource file has become a class in your project with a property for the file.